# Unable to change Windows Firewall settings

Tags: windows-7, windows, firewall, windows-firewall

I am unable to access the settings for Windows Firewall on my Windows 7 32-bit computer.

I go to System and Security (Start > Control Panel > System and Security) and click on Windows Firewall, but nothing happens. If I stop the service, click on Windows Firewall, and then click on turn Windows firewall on or off (on the left) I get this:

[image: Windows Firewall]

What do I need to do to restore the firewall to a working state?

Answer (score 0):

Click on `recommended setting` this will turn on your `windows firewall` after that if you want to allow a program then choose `allow a program or feature through windows firewall`.

if you want turn off your firewall then leave it as it is (according to your image attached currently your firewall is turned off). and `turn off message` from `open action center`.

Hope this may work ..

Comment: I want to turn my firewall on but if I press recommended settings, nothing happens.